# Angular updates data model with wrong values

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to fetch data from YELP - to make sure my template was working, I attached a model to an ng-repeat container. Both methods don't work, what confuses me is that i am updating my list with $scope.list which contains the wrong data and no binding. Using some of the returned API properties, does not update the view as well. Any thoughts?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
                <h3>{{item.id}}</h3>
                <h4>Subheading</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae. Sed dui lorem, adipiscing in adipiscing et, interdum nec metus. Mauris ultricies, justo eu convallis placerat, felis enim.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">View Project <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>






var blogAppViewController = angular.module ('blogAppViewController', []);

blogAppViewController.controller('post_View_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.list = [
        {'title': 'Nexus S','name': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.','link':"data:wMB"},
        {'title': 'Nexus S','name': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.','link':"data:wMB"}
    ];

    function getYELP() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/getyelp'
        });
    };
/////
/////
    $.when(getYELP()).done(function(results) {
        this.yelp_Data = results.businesses;
        $scope.list = this.yelp_Data;
        console.log($scope.list);
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens when I remove all of $scope.list is nothing renders - when it renders with the wrong inputs, the placeholders are actually there. So i dont know why $scope.list is not being returned with data. Doing a console.log shows the returned JSON feed

Comment: You might need to stand up a plunkr/fiddler.  Have you tried $scope.list = angular.copy(this.yelp_Data);  Depending on what you are actually getting back you may even have to use $scope.list = angular.copy(angular.fromJson(this.yelp_Data));  Also you should really use the $http piece from Angular. (it is very nice!)

Comment: Yes Cory, i've tried both of those methods with the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I'm seeing is you are using a jQuery ajax request, which runs outside of the angular [$digest](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24digest) cycle.

So if you want to continue using jQuery(though I'll suggest you use [$http](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/ng.%24http) service) then you need to call [$apply()](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24apply) after modifying the scope values so that the angular framework will become aware about the changes.

```
$.when(getYELP()).done(function (results) {
    this.yelp_Data = results.businesses;
    $scope.list = this.yelp_Data;
    console.log($scope.list);
    if (!$scope.$$phase && !$scope.$root.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem I faced was $http had timing issues and I could not use the results correctly - this method im' sure is retrieving the data - i just can't bind it?

Comment: This doesn't make sense - i am getting the data, I think im trying to bind the wrong type. Hwo can i inspect the object - what properties should it have?

Comment: @seasick your problem http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h92VC/4/ soution http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h92VC/5/

Comment: oh my God ! i didn't try the fiddle yet and it works. thank you so much!!!  Why does the angular framework have to become aware about the changes?

Comment: @seasick that is the basic principle of angularjs... it uses a set of watches to check for changes in the model and then make corresponding changes in the dom/calls handlers

Answer (score 1):

(in surfer voice) "Don't fight the angular".

Try putting your ajax call into a service like this.

**Controller:**

```
.controller('post_View_Ctrl', function ($scope, YelpService) {
    $scope.list = [
        {'title': 'Nexus S','name': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.','link':"data:wMB"},
        {'title': 'Nexus S','name': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.','link':"data:wMB"}
    ];
    $scope.init = function () {
        function success(value) {
            $scope.list = angular.copy(value.businesses);
        }
        function error(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        }
        YelpService.get().then(success, error);
    };
    $scope.init();
});
```

**Service:**

```
.factory('YelpService', function($http, $q){
    return {
        get: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/getYelp')
                .success(function (value) {
                    deferred.resolve(value);
                })
                .error(function (reason) {
                    deferred.reject(reason);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: I like that piece of code - i believe this is putting a global method into my controller? If i want to add another function would i append to .factory}).  like so?

Comment: Definitely. Ideally you could reveal/return more functions than just "get".  Like "getBusinesses" or "getBusinessesByZipcode" whatever you want.  Also since the data is coming from a server that you do not control you can wrap this factory in another that manipulates the datastructure to better suit your needs and then un-manipulates it before it sends it back to the server.